# podman can not refresh containers

Tags: podman, rhel8, rootless

After a recent update on my rehel 8 with podman 3.4.2 on it my containers in a pod including the pod itself are exiting after almost 2 hours.

My OS:

```
$hostnamectl
   Static hostname: DELL
         Icon name: computer-server
           Chassis: server
        Machine ID: 1d0417c6b545caa9f12c94566
           Boot ID: 24f34ee54545w71c01c55c
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 (Ootpa)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

ERRO[0000] Error refreshing container 0beda9a50c18fbc193ec2249bdd76afbe07171df35ace5dd9d47c929ebec682d: error acquiring lock 1 for container 0beda9a50c18fbc193ec2249bdd76afbe07171df35ace5dd9d47c929ebec682d: file exists 
ERRO[0000] Error refreshing container 48329370f65d11178e715c2a065d8ca8883bcfc7961460be3e10a5bf02eb5292: error acquiring lock 3 for container 48329370f65d11178e715c2a065d8ca8883bcfc7961460be3e10a5bf02eb5292: file exists 
ERRO[0000] Error refreshing container fee25dccc31d0fd771a3cc7afcee857c0c0f33af1f7166287a4d8108b7a7605f: error acquiring lock 2 for container fee25dccc31d0fd771a3cc7afcee857c0c0f33af1f7166287a4d8108b7a7605f: file exists 
ERRO[0000] Error refreshing pod 094bfe200b1c9afd9f297facec49f0da40f73e9eb049c339827b2fee10686388: error retrieving lock 0 for pod 094bfe200b1c9afd9f297facec49f0da40f73e9eb049c339827b2fee10686388: file exists
```

**UPDATE**
The problem occures when I log out from the server on which I am loged in with the rootless user!

Comment: podman system renumber did not help either. After 2 hours being up they get exited.

Comment: can they just get stopped by OS after some time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has benn solved by running : loginctl enable-linger $user
as described in https://www.reddit.com/r/podman/comments/h00nfi/rootless_systemd_restarting_containers_when_i_log/